# I have a string that i need to put into an object, but i cant get it to work

Tags: python

I obtain a string: "{{39.830000, -98.580000}, {20.265710, 64.589962}}"
Afterwards, i am triyng to get it to get all the numbers and place it into variables, but it doesnt seem to work.

I was triyng to do

```
t = mystring.split("}, {");
t[0].split(","); #etc...
```

and a bunch of other things... but non seem to work.

Im trying to just place the 4 floats into variabes, a, b, c and d

Comment: You need scope-manipulation, and that's mostly considered as bad/dangerous practice. Check the docs for more info; http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "{{39.830000, -98.580000}, {20.265710, 64.589962}}"
>>> s = s.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]")
>>> l = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> l
[[39.83, -98.58], [20.26571, 64.589962]]
```

Now you've got all your values as `float`s in a nice, indexable `list`.

If you want, you can then do

```
>>> (a, b), (c, d) = l   # Thanks Lev!
>>> a
39.83
>>> # etc.
```

Comment: Keep in mind `eval()` is considered as very dangerous and there should be better methods. Nonetheless, a correct answer :)

Comment: @Allendar: Well yes, that's why I'm not using `eval()`. `ast.literal_eval()` *is* safe.

Comment: @OP: Note that if you really want named variables, it's as simple as `(a, b), (c, d) = l`

Comment: That is awesome!   Thanks a lot for the answer.  I was going to end up just parseing out floats with regex, but this is sooo much better.